# How do I dynamically add columns to a table with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a table with three columns and two rows. I have this code which appends all data to just the first column. I know I am appending all the rows but I am not sure how to change it to add new columns instead.

```
var jdata = [];
$.getJSON(getURL(), function(json) {
    jdata = json.items;
    var menu = [];
    $.each(jdata, function(key, val){
        menu.push("<tr>");
        menu.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+jdata[key].item_code+"</td>");
        menu.push("<tr>");

        menu.push("<tr>");
        menu.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+jdata[key].dish_id+"</td>");
        menu.push("<tr>");

    });
    $("<tbody/>", {html: menu.join("")}).appendTo("table");

});
```

this is what the result looks like:

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
menu.push("<tr>");
menu.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+jdata[key].item_code+"</td>");
menu.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+ `your data here` +"</td>");
menu.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+ `your data here` +"</td>");
menu.push("</tr>");
```

Also as mentioned by [@christophano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/867530/christophano), you need to close your tr like this, `</tr>` instead of just this `<tr>`

Comment: Don't forget to make the last `tr` a closing tag - `</tr>`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the </tr> error. That still didnt fix the issue. It seems  i am appending to the table everytime as opposed to appending to the next column. Any idea how i an do that? TIA!